# Call Jssor Slider Transition during onclick event

Tags: javascript, jssor

I am new to this *jssor* slider animation.I am trying to update the *jssor* slider transition from one effect to other during button click. Ex. if the slider transition effect is fade-in , then after button click it should be fade-out.

I have tried few options like `SetCaptionTransitions()`, `setSlideshowTransitions()`, changing the slider options. but i did not work out. I need help on this.

Regards,
Neji

Answer (score 0):

```
jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{ $Duration: 800, x: 0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }]]);
```

on button click

```
jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{ $Duration: 800, x: 0.3, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 }]]);
```

See example here
https://www.jssor.com/slideshow/x-fade.html

view-source:https://www.jssor.com/slideshow/x-fade.html